# ngFor is delaying display until next item is pushed to array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I have uploader component which works as dropzone for files. When i drop files there they are going to `files: File[]` . I want to display them by ngFor so user knows what uploads. The problem is when i upload file the buffer transforms it to `urls: []`. I checked this in debugger and the values of urls were actually there. But *ngFor doesn't display them until i hover next image on dropzone (just hover, no drop). The scenario looks like this:
I upload image and no images are displayed by ngFor.
I hover second image over dropzone and first image is displayed.
I drop second image and then still first image is displayd.
Then i hover another and shows second.

This is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/core/services/storage.service';
import { AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/core/services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploader',
  templateUrl: './uploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploader.component.scss']
})
export class UploaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  eventSubscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  @Input() productIdEvent: Observable<void>;
  @Input() resetEvent: Observable<void>;
  @Output() onChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  isHovering: boolean;

  files: File[] = [];
  urls = [];

  task: AngularFireUploadTask;

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private productService: ProductService) { }
  
  toggleHover(event: boolean) {
    this.isHovering = event;
  }
  onDrop(files: FileList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      this.files.push(files.item(i));
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(files.item(i)); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed=
        this.urls.push(reader.result);
      }
    }
  }

  uploadFiles(productId){
    let id = 0;
    for(let file of this.files){
      this.storageService.uploadFile(file,productId + "/"+(++id))
      let reader = new FileReader();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventSubscriptions.push(this.productIdEvent.subscribe(val => this.uploadFiles(val)));
    this.eventSubscriptions.push(this.resetEvent.subscribe(() => this.files = []));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.eventSubscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  }
}
```

And html

```
<div class="dropzone" dropzone (hovered)="toggleHover($event)" (dropped)="onDrop($event)" [class.hovering]="isHovering">
    <h3>Strefa zrzutu</h3>
</div>
<div><img *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url"></div>
<div>{{files.length}} zdjęcia</div>
```

directive

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dropzone]'
})
export class DropzoneDirective {

  @Output() dropped = new EventEmitter<FileList>();
  @Output() hovered = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.dropped.emit($event.dataTransfer.files);
    this.hovered.emit(false);
  }

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.hovered.emit(true);
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
  onDragLeave($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.hovered.emit(false);
  }

}
```

Comment: looks like a bug with your change detection. maybe caused by the `dropzone` directive or whichever library is providing that. it's probably messing with `ngZone` for performance reasons and doesn't realize the implications of it.

Comment: @bryan60 updated

Comment: hm.. looks fine. are you using `OnPush` change detection somewhere higher up in your component tree? If not, you might want to recreate this in a stackblitz (without the storage / upload / fire base stuff)

Comment: yes, dropzone is part of a form. I deleted OnPush from parent component but it didn't helped

Comment: this all looks fine enough to me if you're not creating an onpush part of the tree. not clear what you're trying to do inside your `uploadFiles` function where you instantiate a `FileReader` and then do nothing with it, but idk what you expect to happen there.  i'd try to recreate this in a stack blitz.

Comment: @bryan60 forgot to delete it, its useless

Comment: weird bug. I saw in debugger that this.urls.push pushes actual value. So there are values in model, but *ngFor doesnt display them until i hover dropzone with another image.

Comment: It sounds like a change detection bug if the actual values in the array are correct but the display is not. A lot of things can cause change detection bugs. So, I think you'll need to recreate this issue in a blitz.